# How do I sync iPad to iTunes without losing iCloud stuff

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, ipad

I have an iPad that has never been synced, It was just set up with an iCloud account originally. I now want to sync it to my laptop to get my photo albums on it, but when I plug it into itunes I am given the option to restore from a backup (taken from my iPhone, so I don't want that) or to set up as a new iPad (I also don't want that, because it sounds like it will wipe the contents (any iCloud data and any apps, etc.).

How do I go about syncing it to this computer without wiping it?

Comment: Would you consider backing up to iCloud, setting it up with the computer restoring it from an iCloud backup, and going from there? There may be a better solution, but that would work as a last resort.

Comment: When you connect your iPad to the computer for the first time, it asks if you want to setup as a new iPad (I don't think it wipes data here, it just registers it as a new iPad), or if you want to restore data from a backup. iCloud data shouldn't be lost, so if you have a backup there and "set up as a new iPad" you can restore from iCloud backup if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up the iPad as new on iTunes will **not wipe your data**.  Just make sure if you have an older version of iTunes to uncheck "automatically sync apps".  Once you go through that step, click on the photos tab and select the albums you would like to sync from your computer.